# PHP appendChild giving nice fatal error -Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Hierarchy Request Error - how can I add html AFTER a tag

Tags: php, dom, appendchild

In my piece of code I'm trying to find all img tags using PHP DOM, add another img tag directly after and then wrap all of that in a div, i.e.

```
<!-- From this... -->
<img src="originalImage.jpg" />

<!-- ...to this... -->
<div class="wrappingDiv">
    <img src="originalImage.jpg" />
    <img src="newImage.jpg" />
</div>
```

This is the PHP that I'm <strike>bastardising</strike> trying:

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($the_content_string);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    //get all images and chuck them in an array
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
            //create the surrounding div
    $div = $image->ownerDocument->createElement('div');
    $image->setAttribute('class','main-image');
        $added_a = $image->parentNode->insertBefore($div,$image);
        $added_a->setAttribute('class','theme-one');
        $added_a->appendChild($image);
            //create the second image
    $secondary_image = $image->ownerDocument->createElement('img');
    $added_img = $image->appendChild($secondary_image);
    $added_img->setAttribute('src', $twine_img_url);
    $added_img->setAttribute('class', $twine_class);
    $added_img->appendChild($image);
    }

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Everything up to where I create the $added_img variable works fine. Well, at the very least it doesn't error. It's those last four lines that kill it dead.

I'm clearly doing something relatively idiotic... Any lovely, lovely people out there able to point out where I've douched things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

You are trying to append and image to an image here(but of course in HTML an image cannot have an child-image, append the images to the div):

```
$added_img = $image->appendChild($secondary_image);
```

it has to be

```
$added_img = $added_a->appendChild($secondary_image);
```

and again here:

```
$added_img->appendChild($image);
```

has to be:

```
$added_a->appendChild($image);
```

But this will not work at all, because NodeList's are live. As soon as you append one new image, this image is a part of $images, you will run into an infinite loop. So first populate an array with the initial images instead of using a NodeList.

```
$imageList= $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$images=array();
for($i=0;$i<$imageList->length;++$i)
{
  $images[]=$imageList->item($i);
}
```

Comment: OK, so just to make it clear in my own head, what you say I'm doing in my code is this:

Comment: OK, so just to make it clear in my own head, what you say I'm doing in my code is this?:

<img src="xxx"> <img src="yyy" /> </img>

Basically inserting an image into another image rather than just adding the second image after the original image? Is that right?

Secondly, you're saying that because I'm reassigning this to the $image that this is then being added to the $images array and basically adding images within images within images ad inifinitum?

Just want to get that clear, I hate not understanding things properly!

Comment: The first assumption is correct. Regarding to the second: the problem is not the $image-variable,  the problem is $images. $images is a reference to a NodeList, a Live-collection of all `<img/>`'s inside the document. Everytime you add an new image(or remove an image), this NodeList will be modified. So in that case here: when you add a new image, the next loop will access the newly created image.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see, so $images isn't a snapsnot of the nodes at the particular point in time that I assigned the getElementsByTagName() to it, it's a real-time view of the nodes and is updated because I'm directly affecting it. Much clearer, thank you : )

So I should create a separate array for the images like you suggest,  run it through a for loop and THEN use the foreach... OK, I'm going to try that, thanks so far!

Comment: OK, AMAZING, NOW I'm getting somewhere! Only problem is that the second image is being added as the first child of the div. Is there either a way to specify at what position the child goes OR am I going to have to clone the original image tag, insert the second image, insert the cloned image tag, then remove the original image because that sounds a little bit inefficient...?

Comment: WAIT!! It's already doing what I want it to, I'm just being a tool! Thanks Dr.Molle, you legend!